# How to write a custom Orchard session locator by implementing Orchard.Data.ISessionLocator?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, migration, orchardcms

I need to migrate some data in an Orchard module running within a Orchard 1.9.0 installation. The issue here is that the data is stored in a foreign DB on another server, **not** in the Orchard DB. So when the migration class methods get called, internally Orchard uses the `Orchard.Data.ISessionLocator` interface to retrieve the DB connection. Sadly overriding this behavior is not possible but i had the idea to hook into the session locator thing by creating a custom session locator.

The custom session locator looks like this and is based on the existing class `Orchard.Data.SessionLocator`:

```
public class CustomSessionLocator : Orchard.Data.ISessionLocator, Orchard.Data.ITransactionManager, System.IDisposable
{
  // public
    public CustomSessionLocator(Orchard.Data.ISessionFactoryHolder aSessionFactoryHolder)
    {
      Logger = Orchard.Logging.NullLogger.Instance;
      IsolationLevel = System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;

      mSessionFactoryHolder = aSessionFactoryHolder;

      mSessions = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<SessionScope, NHibernate.ISession>();

      if (mForeignDBConnection == null)
      {
        string lConnectionString = "data source=myServer;initial catalog=myDB;persist security info=True;user id=xxx;password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";

        mForeignDBConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(lConnectionString);
      }
    }

    public NHibernate.ISession For(System.Type aEntityType)
    {
      Logger.Debug("Acquiring session for {0}", aEntityType);
      Demand();

      return mSessions[CurrentSessionScope];
    }

    public void Demand()
    {
      EnsureSession(IsolationLevel);
    }

    public void RequireNew()
    {
      RequireNew(IsolationLevel);
    }

    public void RequireNew(System.Data.IsolationLevel aLevel)
    {
      DisposeSession();
      EnsureSession(aLevel);
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
      NHibernate.ISession lSession;

      if (mSessions.TryGetValue(CurrentSessionScope, out lSession) && lSession != null && !lSession.Transaction.WasRolledBack && lSession.Transaction.IsActive)
      {
        Logger.Debug("Rolling back transaction");
        lSession.Transaction.Rollback();
      }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      DisposeSession();
    }

    public enum SessionScope
    {
      OrchardDefault, 
      ForeignDB      
    }

    public Orchard.Logging.ILogger Logger { get; set; }
    public System.Data.IsolationLevel IsolationLevel { get; set; }
    public SessionScope CurrentSessionScope { private get; set; }

  // private
    private void DisposeSession()
    {
      NHibernate.ISession lSession;

      if (mSessions.TryGetValue(CurrentSessionScope, out lSession) && lSession != null)
      {
        try
        {
          if (!lSession.Transaction.WasRolledBack && lSession.Transaction.IsActive)
          {
            Logger.Debug("Committing transaction");
            lSession.Transaction.Commit();
          }
        }
        finally
        {
          Logger.Debug("Disposing session");
          var lConnection = lSession.Connection;
          lSession.Close();
          lSession.Dispose();
          lSession = null;

          mSessions[CurrentSessionScope] = null;
        }
      }
    }

    private void EnsureSession(System.Data.IsolationLevel aLevel)
    {
      NHibernate.ISession lSession;

      if (mSessions.TryGetValue(CurrentSessionScope, out lSession) && lSession != null)
        return;

      var lSessionFactory = mSessionFactoryHolder.GetSessionFactory();
      Logger.Debug("Opening NHibernate session");

      if (CurrentSessionScope == SessionScope.ForeignDB)
      {
        lSession = lSessionFactory.OpenSession(mForeignDBConnection);

        // open connection otherwise the following lSession.BeginTransaction() fails with exception
        if (mForeignDBConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
          mForeignDBConnection.Open();
      }
      else
        lSession = lSessionFactory.OpenSession();

      mSessions[CurrentSessionScope] = lSession;

      lSession.BeginTransaction(aLevel);
    }

    private readonly Orchard.Data.ISessionFactoryHolder mSessionFactoryHolder;
    private System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<SessionScope, NHibernate.ISession> mSessions;
    private static System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection mForeignDBConnection;
}
```

Then i have a migration data interpreter that looks like this:

```
public class ForeignDataMigrationInterpreter : Orchard.Data.Migration.Interpreters.DefaultDataMigrationInterpreter
{
  public ForeignDataMigrationInterpreter(
    Orchard.Environment.Configuration.ShellSettings aShellSettings,
    Orchard.Data.ISessionLocator aSessionLocator,
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Orchard.Data.Migration.Interpreters.ICommandInterpreter> aCommandInterpreters,
    Orchard.Data.ISessionFactoryHolder aSessionFactoryHolder,
    Orchard.Reports.Services.IReportsCoordinator aReportsCoordinator)
    : base(aShellSettings, aSessionLocator, aCommandInterpreters, aSessionFactoryHolder, aReportsCoordinator) 
  {
    mSessionLocator = aSessionLocator as CustomSessionLocator;
  }

  public override void Visit(Orchard.Data.Migration.Schema.CreateTableCommand aCommand)
  {
    #if LIVE
      if (IsForeignDBCommand(aCommand.Name, ""))
        mSessionLocator.CurrentSessionScope = CustomSessionLocator.SessionScope.ForeignDB;
      else
        mSessionLocator.CurrentSessionScope = CustomSessionLocator.SessionScope.OrchardDefault;
    #endif

    base.Visit(aCommand);
  }

  ...

  private bool IsForeignDBCommand(...)
  {
    return ...;
  }

  private CustomSessionLocator mSessionLocator;
}
```

As you can see, the basic procedure with foreign data is

1. Start Orchard
2. `Migration` class method is called which contains `SchemaBuilder.CreateTable()`
3. `ForeignDataMigrationInterpreter.Visit(CreateTableCommand)` is called
4. `CurrentSessionScope` of custom session locator is updated to `SessionScope.ForeignDB`
5. `CreateTableCommand` is passed into `base class`
6. `CustomSessionLocator.For()` is called which
7. ends in `CustomSessionLocator.EnsureSession()` which
8. returns the **session X** for scope `SessionScope.ForeignDB`
9. base class enlists `CreateTableCommand` to transaction of **session X**
10. fast forward some unrelated additional steps and the **transaction is commited BUT it never returns and a timeout exception occures**

My questions are

1. Is it even possible to migrate foreign data this way?
2. Why does timeout occur?

Comment: I'm sorry but that sounds like a really bad idea. What prevents you from creating your own connection to that external database? Why do you need to be in the Orchard nHibernate session?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy Sure, i can do it manually but then i have to write different code for the same scenario (stage and live system whereas DB tables of the live system is partly on another DB). Also i just want to use the migration functionality and all benefits coming with it (SchemaBuilder, migration version, transaction handling)

Comment: Right, it's understandable that you'd want to do that, but all of those features were designed for content parts, and record tables inside the Orchard database, not as general-purpose data access components. If you are using an external database, you should use tools that are not Orchard-specific.